# Execute time every steps in JUnit

Tags: selenium, time, webdriver, jmeter, junit4

I'm stuck on some task over 2 days. I have JUnit test, which will be executed on JMeter, here's the code:

```
public class LoadTest5 extends TestCase {
private WebDriver driver;

public LoadTest5(){}

public LoadTest5(String testName){
    super(testName);
}

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("link"); //just hide the link
}


@Test
public void testTestLoad() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authLogin")).sendKeys("LoadTest5");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authPassword")).sendKeys("Abc123");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:btnLogin")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='settingsLink']/a")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='logout']")).click();
        System.out.println();
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

I will run this test in 5 thread in JMeter, and I need to write execute time for all steps. For example Step - Login:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authLogin")).sendKeys("LoadTest5");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authPassword")).sendKeys("Abc123");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:btnLogin")).click();
```

Count for how long it will execute and write to .csv, and do it with other steps. I can do it with one test, but if it will be 2 and more I can't work with one .csv file. 
How can I do it? 
May be the are some way to do it in JMeter, and make a Graph result?

Comment: Note the annotations on your methods will be ignored, because your test extends `junit.framework. TestCase`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split your steps into separate JUnit Requests like

- [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

  - JUnit Request - Initialize FirefoxDriver(s)
- Main Thread Group

  - JUnit Request - Open Login Page
  - JUnit Request - Perform Login
  - JUnit Request - Perform Logout
- [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

  - Junit Request - Quit Firefox Driver

You can also use [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) plugin which provides seamless integration of JMeter and Selenium, in that case you will be able to modify your code right in JMeter without having to recompile it in case of changes or updates and split your tests in separate samplers in easier way. See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for migration and usage tips and tricks.

Comment: I need to use java for this. How will be looked my code, if I'll make like you wrote:

    setUp Thread Group
        JUnit Request - Initialize FirefoxDriver(s)
    Main Thread Group
        JUnit Request - Open Login Page
        JUnit Request - Perform Login
        JUnit Request - Perform Logout
    tearDown Thread Group
        Junit Request - Quit Firefox Driver

Can you write please?